# Remove Dynamic row in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to delete dynamic `<tr>` using Angular. But my test was not successful.
I can't find what is the error for this.

`page.component.html`

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async; let i =index;">
   <td>{{ row.code.value }}</td>
   <td>{{ row.desc.value }}</td>
   <td>{{ row.amount }}</td>
   <td style="float: right">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formemodal"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn btn-sm waves-effect waves-light delete"><i class="fa fa-bitbucket" (click)="deleteRow(i)">Delete</i></button>
   </td>
</tr>
```

`page.component.ts`

```
selectedOptions$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(){
}

deleteRow(index) {  
  if(this.selectedOptions$.value.length ==1) {
      return false;  
  } else {
      this.selectedOptions$.value.splice(index, 1); 
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your subject is not updated.

Try changing this

```
this.selectedOptions$.value.splice(index, 1);
```

With

```
const newContent = this.selectedOptions$.value.splice(index, 1); 
this.selectedOptions$.next(newContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not directly act on the `BehaviorSubject` `value` property, as it is an anti-pattern.
Instead, `next()` a new `array`.

```
const slicedArray = this.yourArray.slice(1);
this.selectedOptions$.next(slicedArray);
```

As you can see I've also used `slice`, to produce a new array reference, instead of modifying the old one.